# Конкатенация с регулярными выражениями в PHP

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Интересует такой вопрос. Допустим у меня есть переменная $message = "[+]", и есть какое-нибудь тело сообщения "я здесь [+] вот так!", мне нужно прогнатся по циклу таких сообщений и выявить только те, где присутствует "[+]". Просто конкатенация - думаю начнутся проблемы, т.к. используются спецсимволы, или человек поменяет переменную на ему нужную (например слеш+слеш) и всё полетит. Как можно как-то обезопасить от этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что мешает использовать

```
if(strpos($long_string,$message)!==false){
}
```

?

Comment: совсем про неё забыл, спасибо!)